# RocketMQ order messaging is not working

Tags: rocketmq

I am using RocketMQ and want to produce and consume data orderly.I have follwed the Order Example :
https://rocketmq.apache.org/docs/order-example/

But in consumer listener, message is not coming orderly.
Can any one tell how this Order messaging is working?

Comment: Please show us the code and tell where is going wrong. RocketMQ can only ensure the order in the same queue, so you need to put the ordered message into the same queue which you need to implement in the selector

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the "-o true" option when you created the topic?
For example as follows:

```
sh mqadmin updateTopic -c Default_Cluster -n 192.168.1.2:9876 -t TopicTest -o true -r 8 -w 8
```

Comment: In my case, the topic was creating automatically, not from cmd.And the ploblem has solved.Actually my understanding was wrong before.So the messages will be orderly per queue based i.e. the topic will use only one queue for order messaging.